# Pcap.Net Get gateway address

Tags: c#, pcap, man-in-the-middle, pcap.net

I'm currently working on a MITM-Project with Pcap.Net but now I'm stuck.
To keep it short, I need to get the default gateway address of my selected LivePacketDevice.
Is there an easy way to do this, because I didn't find anything.

Thanks
Termi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
device.GetNetworkInterface().GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses[0].Address
```

Got it :D!